# How to get the Jenkins Job startTime and endTime using REST API?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to get the **startTime** and **endTime** of Jenkins Job using REST API. but I could able to see the two variables related to timing. Those are `timestamp` and `estimatedDuration`. I don't get those values in which format is in. so, How can we convert them into understandable format and how we can get the starttime and endtime of Jenkins Job?

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc for [timestamp](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getTimestamp--) and [duration](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getDuration--) ?

Comment: Hi @lanW. No, I looked at Jenkins REST API. Through API, can we get startTime and endTime of Jenkins Job?

Comment: The javadoc explains the call options and the units they are in.

Comment: ok, Thanks LanW. if you have any reference link, Could you please forward me?

Comment: That was in my first comment.